# Read OST file (outlook 2010/2013) from another computer in network using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, outlook

**How can I read OST file (outlook 2010/2013) from another computer in network using C#**

I can read but only from local system/server. I want to read it from other computer/server in network.I have credentials of other system/server. I couldn't find any article on google

Comment: What happens when you try to access it using a UNC path?

Comment: Also, please confirm this is an OST file and not a PST file. How are you reading the file when it is local?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EWS for getting the job done. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - OST files can only be opened in the context of the profile used to create these files. Unlike PST, then cannot be opened in a different profile.